# Uninstalling Ubuntu or unhiding partition

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

I have 3 disks in my machine. I installed Ubuntu in one of them (2 partitions) but it is impossible to "see" the partition where I installed Ubuntu from the other disks (sysop w7 or winxp) so I tried a partition program but it deleted the empty partition, only. At the end of the HD is 320G but now it's only 232G. How can I unhide this partition or uninstall Ubuntu? thank's in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't  unhide the ubuntu partition as it doesn't have a NTFS ,FAT/FAT32 Format

To uninstall Ubuntu
Boot with live ubuntu Cd and use this tool 
[os uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller)

Answer (score 0):

Windows wont recognize ext format but you can delete ubuntu on Windows by deleting ubuntu partition via windows partition manager, just type Partition in your Windows 7/8 start menu and choose the program.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to wipe the HDD you can use GParted live or something and format it.

Comment: Windows doesn't have to recognize a *filesystem* to be able to *see* and *remove* the partition. It cannot resize ext4 partitions but it can delete them.